# JS : Set a time so that the progress bar is not displayed if the data is read again within a certain number of seconds

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, polling

```
// read data with progress
function nprogressWrapPromise(fn, hide = false) {
    if(hide) {
        // no progress
        return fn()
    }
    // have progress
    const done = nprogressStartLoad();
    return fn().then(() => {
      done();
    });
}

function print(message) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(message);
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

call nprogressWrapPromise multiple times in different places

```
nprogressWrapPromise(async () => {
    return await print("one")
}) 
nprogressWrapPromise(async () => {
    return await print("two")
}) 
nprogressWrapPromise(async () => {
    return await print("three")
})
```

I use the NProgress to when I ask the promise ,the page is display the propress

```
let started = 0;

 function nprogressStartLoad() {
  if (started == 0) {
    window.NProgress.start()
  }
  started++;
  return () => {
    started--;
    if (started <= 0) {
      started = 0;
      window.NProgress.done();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add the time,  in the five seconds,  only the first promise have process, the others promise dont have process.

Comment: try `await nprogressWrapPromise(...)`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
let promise = undefined;
function print(message) {
    if (promise) return promise;
    return promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(message);
            resolve();
            promise = undefined;
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

So, we use `promise` as a semaphor. Whenever a new promise is created, we simply store it into the variable called `promise` and we will proceed reusing this variable instead of creating a promise for references even while the promise is not resolved yet. Once the promise is resolved, we set `promise` to `undefined`, so at the next call of `print` we will have a new `Promise`.

EDIT

Similarly to the semaphore above, you can use another semaphore for your other function:

```
let npprogressWrapPromiseDone = undefined;
// read data with progress
function nprogressWrapPromise(fn, hide = false) {
    if(hide) {
        // no progress
        return fn()
    }
    if (npprogressWrapPromiseDone) return npprogressWrapPromiseDone;
    // have progress
    const done = nprogressStartLoad();
    return npprogressWrapPromiseDone = fn().then(() => {
      done();
    });
}
```

Comment: If repeat call the nprogressWrapPromise in the five seconds, I want to only the call ```fn()```,  don't executive the  ```const done = nprogressStartLoad();fn().then(() => {
      done();
    });```